# Say that a subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is open if for any $x \in G$

Tags: real-analysis

Question:  Say that a subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is open if for any $x \in G$, there exists an $r > 0$ so that $|x−y| < r$ implies that $y \in G$. Prove that $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ if and only whenever $G$ is open, $f^{−1}(G) =\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \in G\}$ is also open.

My try: First, suppose that $f$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$, If $G$ is an open subset, we need to show that $f^{-1}(G)$ is also open.

Then what do I do?

Comment: You surely must know the usual $\epsilon-\delta\;$ definition of continuity...well, apply it!

Answer (score 1):

Take $x\in f^{-1}(G)$. Then $f(x) \in G$. Use the fact that $G$ is open to get an $r > 0$ as in your definition. Write down the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition for what it means for $f$ to be continuous at $x$. Replace $\epsilon$ in that definition by $r$, and see what you get around $x$.